# Continuous function $F(t)=\int_a^bf(x)cos(tx)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

I was wondering if the next problem is a particular case of this exercise:

> If $f$ is continuous on rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]$ and if $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b],$  then the function $F$ defined by the equation $$F(y)=\int_a^bg(x)f(x,y)dx$$ is continuous on $[c,d]$.

And this is the problem:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,\pi/2]$. Prove that function $F:[0,\pi/2]\to \mathbb R$ defined by $$F(t)=\int_a^bf(x)cos(tx)dx$$ is continuous.

Comment: $g \in R$ on $[a,b]$. What is R?

Comment: Riemann integrable @SahibaArora

Comment: In the second integral limits of integration should be $[0, \pi/2]$ as $f$ is defined there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your problem, $f$ is continuous and hence Riemann integrable, and $g(x,t)=\cos(xt)$ is continuous, so you can indeed apply the proposition you mentioned, which proves that the function $F$ in the problem is continuous.

To see that $g(x,t)=\cos(xt)$ is continuous, note that it is a composition $g = \sin\circ \,h$ of two continuous functions, where $h(x,t)=xt$.

Comment: That's a very long way to say "yes".

Comment: I think you mean $g(x,t)=cos(tx)$ is continuous instead of $g(x,t)=sin(tx)$ is continuous

Comment: Yup, thanks, corrected it.

Comment: I suspect that even $F$ is differentiable ..

Comment: maybe.. @Ashkan